# com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0 and above get errors while building

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I upgrade build.gradle in my app:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
}
```

And now when I click "Run app" I get the error:

```
Error:(23, 23) error: cannot find symbol class ...
Error:(35, 47) error: cannot find symbol class ...
Error:(37, 2) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(40, 3) error: cannot find symbol variable ...
Error:(41, 3) error: cannot find symbol variable super
...
```

I make Rebuild Project and "Run app" completed successfully. When I edit code in any class or xml in my project and "Run app" I always get build error.

I'm tired of making rebuilding. The old version 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0' didn't give such errors.

Comment: post both your build.gradle files if possible

Answer (score 0):

you could try any of these :

1. **project settings -> Dependencies and up or down one of my library item -> Apply -> Ok -> Make regenerating R.java.**
2. **File -> Settings (Ctrl+Alt+S) -> Compiler -> Uncheck "Use external build"**
3. **Settings -> Editor -> Auto Import -> Java and make the following changes:**

   **change Insert imports on paste value to All**

   **Add unambigious imports on the fly option as checked**

Hope it work for you.